# creating new rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm trying to create a new path, confirm_path, which takes the user to the page called views/users/confirm.html.erb.The url would show website/users/confirm.

I've tried several different ways of expressing this, but none of them have worked.

In the routes file, I currently have

```
get 'users/confirm.html.erb' => 'users#confirm', as: :confirm
```

but it keeps telling me that the user has no id 'confirm'

Do any of you know how I can create confirm_path, which would just display the info at views/users/confirm.html.erb and show url users/confirm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably defined a users resource above this line, something like

```
resources :users
```

so users/confirm gets routed to `UsersController#show with id='confirm'`.
 Make sure you define

```
get 'users/confirm', to: 'users#confirm', as: :confirm
```

as suggested by Mihail, above the definition of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
get 'users/confirm.html.erb' => 'users#confirm', as: :confirm
```

to:

```
get 'users/confirm', to: 'users#confirm', as: :confirm
```

Also add in you `UsersController`:

```
def confirm
end
```

Comment: hmm, this still sin't working. It's still flagging this function:  def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end and stating "couldn't find user with 'id'= confirm

Comment: same as before: "couldn't find user with 'id'= confirm". also if I instead try users/confirm.html.erb, I get: No route matches [GET] "/users/confirm.html.erb"